# Get all public Instagram posts with shopping/product tags

Tags: facebook-graph-api, instagram, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

I’m trying to get all public posts on Instagram which have a shopping or product tag. Is that possible using Instagram’s graph api or basic display api?

I explored the get endpoint but I can’t seem to find any filter to get images with shopping tags. You can only do it too get your own shop’s catalogue but I’m trying to get anyone’s public post with shopping tag. There are also a couple of ways to get photos with specific hashtags, but couldn’t find anything to filter out shopping tag-only photos.